# Why am I receiving "PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission"?

Tags: video-intelligence-api

I am trying to run python samples from GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples using Video Intelligence API. Specifically, I am receiving Permission Denied 403 when I am running the command "python3 beta_snippets.py streaming-labels resources/cat.mp4"

- **Solutions attempted:**

1. Supplying Google Application Credentials with 'gcloud auth application-default login'
2. Supplying Google Application Credentials with downloaded .json key
3. Creating another service account

- **Steps to recreate problem:**
  source /home/[REDACTED]/bin/activate

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED].json

cd /home/[REDACTED]/python-docs-samples/videointelligence/samples/analyze

python3 beta_snippets.py streaming-labels resources/cat.mp4

- **Error Log:**
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/[REDACTED]/python-docs-samples/videointelligence/samples/analyze/beta_snippets.py", line 902, in 
  detect_labels_streaming(args.path)
  File "/home/[REDACTED]/python-docs-samples/videointelligence/samples/analyze/beta_snippets.py", line 256, in detect_labels_streaming
  responses = client.streaming_annotate_video(requests, timeout=600)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/videointelligence_v1p3beta1/services/streaming_video_intelligence_service/client.py", line 750, in streaming_annotate_video
  response = rpc(
  ^^^^
  File "/home/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 131, in **call**
  return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 293, in retry_wrapped_func
  return retry_target(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 153, in retry_target
  _retry_error_helper(
  File "/home/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_base.py", line 212, in _retry_error_helper
  raise final_exc from source_exc
  File "/home/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 144, in retry_target
  result = target()
  ^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 120, in func_with_timeout
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 174, in error_remapped_callable
  raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
  google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission